# PHP include a URL querystring as well as a variable

Tags: php, include

I have been experimenting with query strings to load content dynamically within a div on a page. A normal include without a query string works fine. However, when I add a query string and variable, a page is not returned. Is there an alternative method of doing this - if this is not possible

**index.php**

```
<a href="?blogs=1">BLOGS</a>

if (isset($_GET['blogs'])) {
    $link = $_GET['blogs'];
    if ($link == '1') {
        include('/controller/blogs/viewBlogs.php?blogid=$blogid');
        $linkclicked = true;
    }
}
```

index.php has a link to listBlogs.php which opens a list of blogs in index.php's content div with a query string linking to each individual blog. The query strings link to the viewBlogs.php page.

I.e. blogid=29.

**listBlogs.php**

```
<a href='/controller/blogs/viewBlogs.php?blogid=$blogid'>View blog '$title'</a>";
```

When clicking on a link in listBlogs.php it takes me to a separate page containing the specific information for the blogid in viewBlogs.php.

**viewBlogs.php**

I want the blogId taken from listBlogs.php to be taken and open the viewBlogs.php page with that specific blogid in the content div in the index.php page.

Thanks.

Comment: query strings pass data from browser(html) to server(php).
to pass data from server(php page) code to another(php code), use functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, define the variables beforehand (before your include call, that is):

```
if (isset($_GET['blogs'])) {
    $link = $_GET['blogs'];
    if ($link == '1') {
        $blogid="1234";
        include('/controller/blogs/viewBlogs.php');
        $linkclicked = true;
    }
}
```

Or use a superglobal like `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` in `viewBlogs.php` directly (that's what it's all about in the first place anyway).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have clarified my problem further above. This solution didn't work.